# GZIP Compression through .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, gzip

My website loading speed is much low. 
[My Website Link](http://cableandmedia.com/secondsight/)

On testing my site on google page speed tool, I came to know that by GZIP will effective to solve this issue.
I wants to know how to do gzip compression via .htaccess

Comment: Try this if it helps https://varvy.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you already have a `.htaccess` file on the webroot. Then include following codes into your `.htaccess` file.

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

You can be make sure whether gzip is enabled using following steps

1. Open chrome browser and press F12 open chrome developer tool
2. Enter your web url. Once web site is loaded, you would see response header

like below screenshot if gzip is enabled. (see attached screenshot)

[image]